# HTML inserting text in the upper border of a box in css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to insert a text with the upper side of a box using CSS, but I can't come up with anything to make it happen. this is my code so far:

```
.boxed{
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 300px;
    height: 180px;
}
```

and this is what I want to do:
[image]

how do i insert a text in the upper border of a box?

***im already done with this thanks guys. but my problem now is putting pagination on tabs. can u help me? the rest of the code is in here:**

http://jsfiddle.net/3y539gvq/

Comment: What's your ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) HTML for this?

Comment: You can use a `fieldset/legend` combo - http://jsfiddle.net/cj9mxfhj/

Comment: @Paulie_D nice, wish i thought of that :)

Comment: @88MPG Yeah...if you don't care about semantics.

Comment: guys i have another question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your box to relative positioning and position the label using absolute positioning. Also, I'd recommend setting the background of your container, and inheriting the background in the label CSS to keep the two consistent.

```
.boxed {
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 300px;
    height: 180px;
}
.label {
    background: inherit;
    padding: 0 5px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: -10px;
}

<div class="boxed">
    <span class="label">General Information</span>
</div>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/b7a29fsd/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
.boxed {
    ... your existing styles ...
    position:relative;
}


.boxed:after {
   position:absolute;
   top:-5px;
   left:15px;
   padding:3px;
   content: "your label text";
   background-color: (something to cover up the border underneath)
}
```

Comment: Using content wouldn't allow this style to be re-usable for multiple boxes.

Comment: That would really depend on whether you need different labels, which could also be done with other classes that only define `content:

Comment: Good idea, but I'd still rather inline the label for visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a text within the div you have like so:

```
<div> 
    <p> Some text </p> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.boxed{
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 300px;
    height: 180px;
    position:absolute;
}

.boxed p{
    position:relative;
    top:-28px;
    left:5px;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:white;
    width:80px;
}
}
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh0godfa/).

Comment: my problem now is putting pagination on tabs. can u help me? the rest of the code is in here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3y539gvq/